# How to handle frozen process in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, process, amazon-ec2, passenger

I have nginx + passenger server(API) in my ec2 instance, several requests have been made in to the server within a minute, sometime it freezes the swagger UI is not loading and all the api requests are failed with the error
`Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout`, but there is no error in my nginx log after restarting the server then works fine but after some time passenger has more number of queues

How do i trace errors and how to fix it?

`passenger-status`

Version : 4.0.50
Date : 2014-09-19 03:48:43 +0000
Instance: 3551
----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 6
Processes : 6
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/home/ubuntu/project#default:
App root: /home/ubuntu/project
Requests in queue: 742

```
PID: 4726 Sessions: 1 Processed: 118 Uptime: 13h 32m 37s CPU: 0% Memory : 297M Last used: 12h 4m
PID: 19098 Sessions: 1 Processed: 2751 Uptime: 12h 8m 31s CPU: 0% Memory : 476M Last used: 4h 36m 2
PID: 20545 Sessions: 1 Processed: 318 Uptime: 12h 0m 34s CPU: 0% Memory : 439M Last used: 9h 44m 3
PID: 23003 Sessions: 1 Processed: 208 Uptime: 11h 48m 28s CPU: 0% Memory : 290M Last used: 10h 36m
PID: 1119 Sessions: 1 Processed: 622 Uptime: 10h 48m 28s CPU: 0% Memory : 442M Last used: 7h 44m
PID: 3856 Sessions: 1 Processed: 461 Uptime: 10h 32m 34s CPU: 0% Memory : 420M Last used: 8h 16m
```

Most of the connections are still open

`rvmsudo passenger-status --show=requests | grep connected`

```
connected at                = 2014-09-22 06:47:05 (2835 sec ago)
connected at                = 2014-09-22 06:39:04 (3315 sec ago)
connected at                = 2014-09-22 05:40:07 (6853 sec ago)
connected at                = 2014-09-22 06:39:04 (3315 sec ago)
connected at                = 2014-09-22 05:04:05 (9015 sec ago)
connected at                = 2014-09-22 06:39:04 (3315 sec ago)
```

I set timeout in nginx as 180 seconds but still more number of connections are still open even 9000 seconds ago

I got comment in [github](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1282) like frozen process, anyone guide me to handle frozen process caused by passenger server in linux?